# Custom RepositoryItemProgressBar

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Hello i want to create my own RepositoryItemProgressBar. So that enduser can choose value in the ProgressBar. Normaly the ProgressBar only shows the value but is not editable.
My Problem is starting to write own RepositoryItem. I cant find the Item in the Grid Designer to bind it on column.

I tried following:

```
[UserRepositoryItem("RegisterBxProgressBar")]
public class RepositoryItemBxProgressBar : RepositoryItemProgressBar
{
    internal static string EditorName = "BxProgressBar";

    static RepositoryItemBxProgressBar()
    {
        Register();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registriert die Komponente
    /// </summary>
    public static void Register()
    {
        EditorRegistrationInfo.Default.Editors.Add(new EditorClassInfo(EditorName, typeof(ProgressBarControl),
            typeof(RepositoryItemBxProgressBar), typeof(ProgressBarViewInfo), new ProgressBarPainter(), true,
            EditImageIndexes.ProgressBarControl, typeof(DevExpress.Accessibility.ProgressBarAccessible)));
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can help me how to start with a new RepositoryItem?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear to me why do not use the [TrackBarControl](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsTrackBarControltopic) which is specially designed to provide capability to edit value via dragging thumb.
Anyway you should start from the [Custom Editors](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4716) help article when creating custom editors.

Yet another way is demonstrated in the following example:
[How to create TrackBarControl with ProgressBar instead of a track line](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3286)